# Treat and solve the system of equations in dependence of parameter a

Tags: linear-algebra

The task gives and asks to treat and solve the system of equations in dependence of parameter $a$. The system given:

$x + y - z = 1$

$2x + 3y + az = -1$

$x + ay + 3z = 13$

I used Gaussian elimination method to get the equation to solve for $a$, but I always end up with wrong value so I can't treat the system any further.

I transformed the original matrix to this:
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
    6 & 9 & 3a & -3 \\
    a & a^2 & 3a & 13a \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
which has led me to the equation $6 - a + 9 - a^2 = 13a$, but this is the wrong result.

Comment: Can you show us your working?

Comment: Why do you solve for $a?$  As I understand the question, you should solve for $x,y,z$ in terms of $a.$

Comment: Yes, but in order to solve for $x, y, z$ you must find possible values of $a$ that you can work with. I apologize for misuse of terminology as english is not my first language.

Comment: @cki I upvoted because I think that your approach is logical.  However, shouldn't your last equation be $6-a+9-a^2 = -3-13a.$

Comment: Why don't you try to find the value of $x,y,z$ using cross multiplication and put it in one of the equations by treating $a$ as constant?

Comment: @LoveInvariants I think that your comment is interesting.  I assert that the questioner's intent was to identify all legitimate values of $a$ and identify, for each such value, whether (x,y,z) has no values, 1 value, or an infinite number of values.  This may be done by either taking your approach, which **first** links (x,y,z) to $a$, or ckl's approach, which first identifies legitimate values for $a$.

Comment: For anyone following - I calculated the determinant of the matrix (from coefficients of $x, y, z$) which gave me the possible values of $a$.